# What are the possibilities to compile and create apex code through api

Tags: apex, api, deployment, tooling-api, change-set

I have an app that creates apex classes for some purposes, right now we are using **Tooling Api**, but some objects are not entirely accessible with it (e.g. **developerName** in RecordType Object). So my question is is there a way to overcome this limitation (e.g. **REST API** or **SOAP API** etc.)

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? You want to use one single API to create record types, apex classes, and update records, or something?

Comment: I wish to create/delete apex classes to/from org

Comment: For what kind of org? Production? Sandbox? Developer Edition?

Comment: Sandbox........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, for non-production orgs, you have several options available.

## [Tooling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm)

### Create

```
POST /services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass
```

### Update

```
PATCH /services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/:Id
PATCH /services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/:Name
```

### Delete

```
DELETE /services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/:Id
DELETE /services/data/vXX.X/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/:Name
```

### [Metadata Container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacontainer.htm)

For deploying multiple ApexClass objects (and other code) in a single deployment. See the documentation for this, it is relatively complex.

## [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)

### Create

```
POST /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/ApexClass
```

### Update

```
PATCH /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/ApexClass/:Id
PATCH /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/:Name
```

### Delete

```
DELETE /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/ApexClass/:Id
DELETE /services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/:Name
```

## SOAP

### Create

```
create(ApexClass)
```

### Delete

```
delete(ApexClass)
```

## [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm)

### Create/Update

```
deployMetadata(ApexClass)
```

### Delete

```
deleteMetadata(ApexClass)
```

Comment: If i use REST for example must i configurate my app as a "connected app"?